# Spring Boot Application quits unexpectedly with "Killed"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services, spring-boot

I am running a small webservice application with Spring Boot, Maven, Spring Data, Hibernate which is usually working fine. It has just a single webservice request mapping. The application is a standalone JAR and started in a shell with "screen".

Nearly once per day it just quits itself. There is nobody that forces the app to stop or so. It just says "Killed" in the shell. There is no exception, error or any other message. I already tried to activate logging in **application.properties** with:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

but that does not help. Also added exception handling to the webservice mapping trying to catch any exception thrown. But also nothing.

Does anyone know why the app could have been stopped or how I can display the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find some information in `/var/log/messages`, since it sounds like OS might be killing your service.

Comment: Try lowering the logging from `ERROR` to `INFO` and widen the scope to `logging.level.org.springframework`. Also, consider not running your app in 'screen' and use an init.d script and `service` (Spring Boot 1.3+ has one built in; just symlink it to /etc/init.d).

Comment: Hello @Hoax what actually worked for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered with the same problem and I had resolved it by creating swap area. I think it is a typical memory problem. I recommend you to create swap area if you are deploying the application in a linux environment. Check memory usage before..

Answer (score 5):

This happens often when system kills your Java process because it started to consume a lot of memory.

Try to inspect your deployment target limitations and adjust heap size below that limit.

Comment: Thank you. I wil ltry that an report back if it worked.